# How to use evaluate_generator in keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

When I have trained a model and save the params as hdf5 file, and then I try to evaluate the performance of the model on `test_dataset`, but there is something wrong in `param metrics` of `model.compile`, if I set `metrics` as

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam,
              loss=losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=[cus_acc, miou])
```

It will occurs an Error as follow:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [`labels` out of bound] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/control_dependency:0) = ] [107 118 135...] [y (metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/Cast_2:0) = ] [2]  [[Node: metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_INT64, DT_STRING, DT_INT64], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch/_3827, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_0, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_2, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_1/_3829, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/data_4, metrics/cus_acc/confusion_matrix/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert/Switch_2/_3831)]]
```

Notes that optimizer `adam` have been defined, and `cus_acc` and `miou` are customized metrics. If delete the metrics it works, so I think there must be something wrong in it, `miou` and `cus_acc` are both calculate by the `confusion_matrix`.
**My Question** is what makes the error occurs and how to use evaluate_generator to evaluate model performance in keras, if you can provide example code that the best~
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved.
The error occurs when creating confusion_matrix, the `nb_classes` i.e. 0, 1, 2 must match the label in the `ground-truth` 0, 1, 2. For example, the ground-truth is not preprocessed and the value of pixels are 0, 127, 255. And then the `InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed` will occur.
What made my code wrong is not due to the customized metrics, it is when I create a data_generator for ground-truth, the `param directory` was set the same as the `images`.